# How can I get the section.subsection number without the chapter number?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

How do I get the number of the current subsection in a report, without the chapter number? What I'm wanting to do is produce a requirements list as follows using the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{requirements}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[requirements]{label=\textbf{R\thesubsection.\arabic*}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Requirements}
\section{Functional Requirements}
\subsection{Requirements Category}
Some information about ``requirements category'' goes here.
\begin{requirements}
    \item First Requirement
    \item Second Requirement
\end{requirements}
\subsection{Different Requirements Category}
Foo bar baz. Herpeddy Derpeddy.
\begin{requirements}
    \item This is a first requirement
    \item This is a second requirement
\end{requirements}
\section{Non-functional Requirements}
\subsection{Category}
Category category category.
\begin{requirements}
    \item First NFR
    \item Another NF-Requirement
\end{requirements}
\end{document}
```

This produces lists of the **R1.1.1.1**, **R1.1.1.2**, etc.

What I'd like is lists of the form **R1.1.1**, **R1.1.2**, with the list in the next subsection being **R1.2.1**, **R1.2.2** and so on.

Comment: Is it worth me generalising this question a bit and removing my particular example of wanting to use the value in a list, or should I leave the question as is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change `\thesubsection` to `\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}` .

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I knew it'd be something obvious, I just didn't know how to search for it!