# How can I number paragraphs without higher level counters?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, titlesec

How can I redefine the paragraph counter such that instead of revealing all superior counters, it only reveals the paragraph counter. I assume this is possible with `titlesec`.

**I would like to have each paragraph numbered like §1, §2, §3, etc.**

See minimal example below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcounter{paragraphstep}
\newcommand{\paracount}{%
        \stepcounter{paragraphstep}%
        \theparagraphstep}
        \setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{}\label{Personal Statement}
San Francisco is a city in California. See paragraph \ref{Personal Statement}.

\end{document}
```

This question is related to:

- [How can I get the section.subsection number without the chapter number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53718/how-can-i-get-the-section-subsection-number-without-the-chapter-number)
- [numbering of \paragraph command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61078/numbering-of-paragraph-command)

Comment: Add the line `\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\S~\arabic{paragraph}}`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default paragraphs are numbered within subsections, restarting at 1 at each subsection.  If you just wish to changed the printed representation of the paragraph number then all you need is

```
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\S\arabic{paragraph}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

If you wish the paragraphs to also be numbered consecutively throughout the document then you can use the `chngcntr` package's command `\counterwithout` to undo the resetting as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\S\arabic{paragraph}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\paragraph{}\label{Personal Statement}
San Francisco is a city in California.

\subsection{A subsection}

\paragraph{}
San Francisco is a city in California.  See paragraph \ref{Personal
Statement}.

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\paragraph{}
San Francisco is a city in California.

\section{Second section}

\paragraph{}
San Francisco is a city in California. See paragraph \ref{Personal Statement}.

\paragraph{}
San Francisco is a city in California.


\end{document}
```

*Added in response to comment* To adjust the spacing after numbers etc. it is probably easiest to use the `titlesec` package.  There are two commands involved here: `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing`.  If you never intend to give titles to your paragraphs then the `\titlespacing` command below is sufficient.  The `\titleformat` command makes sure words in a paragraph heading are also handled appropriately:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\S\arabic{paragraph}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{\wordsep}{}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{\wordsep}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\paragraph{}\label{Personal Statement}
San Francisco is a city in California.

\subsection{A subsection}

\paragraph{}
San Francisco is a city in California.  See paragraph \ref{Personal
Statement}.

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\paragraph{}
San Francisco is a city in California.

\section{Second section}

\paragraph{}
San Francisco is a city in California. See paragraph \ref{Personal Statement}.

\paragraph{With title}
San Francisco is a city in California.

\end{document}
```

The arguments given to `\titlespacing` are as follows:

- section command = `\paragraph`
- left indent = `0pt`
- above vertical skip = `3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex` the standard value from the article class
- final separation = `\wordsep` an ordinary word space

For `\titleformat` the spcification is

- section command = `\paragraph`
- style = `runin` for heads contain in the same paragraph as the text
- format = `\normalfont\bfseries` for styling the heading
- label = `\theparagraph` the printed representation of the section number
- sep = `\wordsep` is the space between the label and the title (when present)
- before code = empty

Comment: Thanks! How would I remove the extra space such that there is only a normal space between the number and the first word of each paragraph? Also, I assume making it not bold is also doable within the `\renewcommand`.

Comment: @macmadness86 Value `4` for the counter `secnumdepth` is enough to show paragraph numbers.

Answer (score 7):

You can use package `scrjura` of KOMA-Script.

An example could be (as @harish requested in his comment ;-):

```
\documentclass[%
  ngerman
 ,paper=a4
 ,fontsize=12pt
 ,parskip=half-
 ,pagesize
 ,numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}% scrreprt scrartcl

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[%
  juratotoc%=1              % juratotoc=0 0 chapter, 1 section
 ,paragraphmark=forceboth
 ,juratocnumberwidth=2.5em
]{scrjura}  

\usepackage{enumerate}

\makeatletter
% to get rid of a warning ...
\providecommand*{\toclevel@cpar}{0}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\subject{Subject}
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{}   % no author: {} empty
%\date{}    % no date

\maketitle  % setzt den Titel der Satzung

\addsec{Preface}
A preface, if you need it.


%\clearpage 
\appendix % Letters instead of numbers

\section{Section One}
\begin{contract}
\Paragraph{title={Title first paragraph}}
The content of first paragraph.

A list of posibilities:
\begin{enumerate}[\qquad a)]
  \item first.
  \item second.
  \item third.
\end{enumerate}

The content of third paragraph.
\end{contract}

\section{Section Two}
\begin{contract}
\Paragraph{title={Title first paragraph}}
The content of first paragraph.
\end{contract}

\end{document}
```

With the result:

[image]