# \paragraph & \label{}

Tags: cross-referencing, include

I am working with about 4000 aphorisms and this is the way I structured my document. 
I created 4000 sections in one document and named it "aphorisms" i.e.

```
\section{aphorism - 1} \label{1.1.1} 
\section{aphorism - 1} \label{1.1.2} and so on
```

I can not change the label name because thats how they are numbered and I don't want loose this reference.

Then I ran the file and it created `aphorisms.aux` file,

For my document Lessons_1 wherever I needed the aphorism quoted I used `\nameref*{}` and I included previously generated aux file and later excluded using `\includeonly{}` to stop the output to PDF.  It created a beautiful document I wanted. Below is non working example, but to show the structure of my documents arrangement.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\RequirePackage{my_Custom_package}

\includeonly{Lessons_1}

\begin{document} 
\doublespacing

\include{aphorisms}
\include{Lessons_1}

\end{document}
```

my question is can it be done like this using paragraphs in place of sections and label names as `\label{a1.1.1}` etc.

This way I can create explanation of each aphorism by various author, by creating something like `\paragraph{  } \label{}` for each author.

Then I can easily create as shown below, This would become template to many other projects I am planning to undertake in future.

```
\nameref*{1.1.1} % aphorism
\nameref*{a1.1.1} % Explanation of Author A
\nameref*{b1.1.1} % Explanation of Author B
```

This project is to revive some ancient texts. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: sorry could not come up with a suitable question title.

Comment: I guess that you have to increase the value of `\secnumdepth` to turn on numbering for paragraphs.

Comment: @Sigur - can you please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: On preamble `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`. Test other values if necessary.

Comment: For paragraphs you need `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}`, cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126764/15925

Comment: @AndrewSwann & Sigur thanks for your help. It worked, also by accident I was putting extra space in \Label{} that caused ?? in the output. I put both and now its working again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarise the comments: to make paragraph labels visible one should write

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

in the preamble.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\section{Aphorisms}

\paragraph{Aphorism - 1}\label{1.1.1} 
Life is short, art long, opportunity fleeting, experience deceptive,
judgment difficult.

\section{Explanations}

\nameref*{1.1.1} is take from the Wikipedia page on aphorisms and is
the first sentence of Hippocrates' \emph{Aphorisms}.

\end{document}
```