# Numbering paragraphs in latex

Tags: formatting, numbering, paragraphs

I would like to number paragraphs for a covering report I am writing. Paragraphs should increment and not reset with new sections. The text should not be bold. Here is what I have tried

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  {\z@}{0.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{10}{15}\selectfont}
  {\arabic{paragraph}}%
}
\makeatother
```

This has been hacked from various questions on this site.

```
  \paragraph{Testing 1}
  \paragraph{Testing 2}
```

gives me

```
0.0.0.1 1 Testing 1
0.0.0.2 2 Testing 2
```

desired format is

```
1 Testing 1
2 Testing 2
```

Where am I going wrong?

Also what is `fontfamily{phv}`. Is this different from my default font?

Comment: Have a look at this answer it might fit for your need. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10524/31058

Comment: @moadeep Are you looking for something like "(19)" at the beginning of a paragraph, or e.g. as a marginpar? Show us what you would like to have!

Comment: @KeksDose Question edited. I would like something like "(19)" at the beginning of each paragraph. The reason being I need to cross reference paragraphs to a table in another chapter

Comment: I guess you have a line like `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}`

Comment: @karlkoeller yes. The number is incrementing as expected. My major issue is the extra 0.0.0.num before num

Comment: Well, remove that line.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`\paragraph` is like `\section` the argument should be the title not the whole paragraph, and it should only be used after a higher level sectioning unit (`\subsubsection`)

Perhaps

```
\newcounter{para}
\newcommand\mypara{\par\refstepcounter{para}\thepara\space}
```

Then you can use

```
\mypara blah blah blah
\mypara foo bar baz
```

Comment: Excellent thanks. Can I make the number bold?

Comment: @moadeep `\textbf{\thepara}`

Comment: Is there a way to make the paragraph title bold also?

Comment: @flamsmark these are untitled paragraphs, if you want titled paragraphs you need something more like `\newcommand\mypara[1]{\par\refstepcounter{para}\textbf{\thepara\space#1\space}}`

Answer (score 16):

This is as simple as:

```
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\S\arabic{paragraph}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

If you just wish to also have them in the table of contents:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
```

Answered taken from [How can I number paragraphs without higher level counters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126750/how-can-i-number-paragraphs-without-higher-level-counters)

Answer (score 8):

Using the idea from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10524/31058):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mparhack}   % get marginpars to always show up on the correct side (need to compile twice)
\usepackage{lipsum}     % for dummy text

\setlength\parindent{0cm}

\newcommand{\parnum}{(\arabic{parcount})}

\newcounter{parcount}
\newcommand\p{%
    \stepcounter{parcount}%
    \parnum \hspace{1em}%
}

\newenvironment{parnumbers}{%
   \par%
   \everypar{\noindent \stepcounter{parcount}\parnum \hspace{1em}}%
}{}

\begin{document}

\p \lipsum[1]

\begin{parnumbers}
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{parnumbers}

\end{document}
```

it yields

[image: Output]

Comment: If you use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter` paragraphs can be used with `\label` / `\ref`

Comment: also, don't do anything rash, like using a list environment (itemize, enumerate, etc) -- they destroy \everypar

Comment: This is the best solution, because it does the numbering automatically within the environment. The other solution requires a command to number the paragraph. So this one is better.

Comment: This breaks if you interpose a `\section{}`.

Comment: @g33kz0r out of interest why does a section break this ?

Comment: How do I reset counter to start from 1 in each parnumbers env?