# Reduce inter-word spacing in run-in \paragraph style

Tags: spacing

I'm quite new to Latex and slowly writing/making my book (electrical measurements, some signal processing, that stuff), but sometimes I get trapped in probably trivial issues.
My first writing is with Lyx (please, understand me, I've been using Word for 25 yrs!) and then ERT and preamble for fine tuning.

`\paragraph` is my last section heading and is of the *run-in* type; I want to keep words tight and avoid interword spacing sticking to a minimum.

I have seen that `\tolerance` and `\wordsep` are two low-level parameters that have to do with that.

*Question*: Is it possible to redefine `\paragraph` reducing \wordsep and words are more packed together?

Here is a small excerpt where "Resonance with a known capacitance (frequency domain, narrow-band)" is way too long.

```
\documentclass[10pt,english]{book}
\usepackage{charter}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{\label{chap:Ch1_Circuits}Circuits and Basic Relationships}

\subsubsection{Experimental determination}

\paragraph{Use of a RCL bridge}
This is the simplest and most straightforward method, provided that the RCL bridge with
adequate performance is available: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 

\paragraph{Resonance with a known capacitance (frequency domain, narrow-band)}
This method works well for many inductors that have non-standard package
(e.g. home made inductors),  including circuits and cables, and when the frequency
range is extended, but not too much. bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

... and Happy Easter

Comment: your question is massively unclear. You need to give an example, tex tries hard to "avoid too much interword spacing" so if you are getting too much it is very hard to say what to change unless you show _why_ you are getting too much.

Comment: also the text of your question does not seem related to the title, which appears to be about kerning for the letter "a" ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: ok, thanks, I work on this, and sorry for the broken title

Comment: No, it's not possible to shrink that title: there's no way “This” can find place on the previous line. By the way, there's no `\wordsep` parameter.

Comment: @egreg -Thank you. Now I am sure and will go for some "hand patching" of the most critical cases. [marginal comment: \wordsep is cited in other 3 threads and I understood it was a low-level parameter].

Comment: I think that's a package-specific token: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126764/17423

Comment: @ Sean Allred -Right, read the link and got it, thanks! I can only improve :$

Comment: The breaking in the example you supplied seems fine, the title is not very stretched even if the white space was shrunk to its minimum amount `This` would not fit (and if it did fit it would look worse with just one non-bold word on the line). If you were breaking this by hand how would you break the lines? what do you want TeX to do differently here?

Comment: @David Carlisle -Yes, got the point better that I could explain (at 2am not all things are clear!). First, shrinking the \paragraph wouldn't produce nice results (I will patch reducing the length, removing some words, etc. .. no other way, and probably it will benefit). Second, the third example you give below is right what I was thinking, and I couldn't write it down, only playing around with syntax: the zero with \z@, \@plus and \@minus. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By  "bad interwrod spacing" are you are pointing to the space between "brigge" and "This"?  In this case, you can redefine `\paragraph` to change this fixed space:

> [image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[10pt ]{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}


\paragraph{Use of a RCL bridge}
This is the simplest and most straightforward method, provided that ...

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  {\z@}{3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-6em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\makeatother

\paragraph{Use of a RCL bridge}
This is the simplest and most straightforward method, provided that ...

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  {\z@}{3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-.3em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\makeatother

\paragraph{Use of a RCL bridge}
This is the simplest and most straightforward method, provided that ...


\end{document}
```