# paragraph numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am using the paragraph section head, i.e.,

```
\paragraph{This is a cool paragraph}
```

I would like it to compile with numbering. If I change the `secnumdepth` (i.e., `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}`) this will work, but produce the "wrong" type of numbering, i.e.,

> 1.1.1.1 This is a cool paragraph
>
> 1.1.1.2 This is another cool paragraph etc.

What I would like is

> 1 This is a cool paragraph
>
> 2 This is another cool paragraph

or, if not,

> 1.1 This is a cool paragraph
>
> 1.2 This is another cool paragraph

where the first 1 indicates the section number and suppresses the subsection and subsubsection numbers. Can this be done?

Comment: `\paragraph` is a 4th level heading and should only be used in the sequence section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph. You should either use \section for top level sections or `itemize` and \item

Comment: having said that, `\renewcommand\theparagraph{\arabic{paragraph}}` will get rid of all the prefixed numbers

Comment: I think the OP just wants to suppress the unwanted numbers, but uses the hierarchy in the usual way.

Comment: Isn't [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126750/how-can-i-number-paragraphs-without-higher-level-counters?rq=1) the same problem?

Comment: @AlexNelson: Yup.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please mark a solutions as solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an `enumitem` way instead of `\paragraph`. The `paragraphlisti` counter is reset by each `subsubsection` step (if such levels are used at all)

David Carlisle's comment about `\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}` is of course the easiest way!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{paragraphlist}{enumerate}{1}


\setlist[paragraphlist,1]{leftmargin=*,label={\bfseries \arabic*}}

\counterwithin{paragraphlisti}{subsubsection}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\subsection{Foo sub}

\subsubsection{Foo subsub}

\begin{paragraphlist}

\item New Paragraph

\item Other Paragraph
\end{paragraphlist}


\section{Bar}

\subsection{Bar sub}

\subsubsection{Bar subsub}

\begin{paragraphlist}

\item New Paragraph

\item Other Paragraph
\end{paragraphlist}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the article class the hierarchy of levels is `\section -> \subsection -> \subsubsection -> \paragraph`. Paragraphs don't get numbers.

In the book class the hierarchy of levels is `\chapter -> \section -> \subsection -> \subsubsection -> \paragraph`

If you want to use custom numbering for paragraphs, call their values and edit their counters. i .e.

```
\setcounter{paragraph}{1}
\paragraph{\arabic{paragraph} New Paragraph}
Text here
\stepcounter{paragraph}
\paragraph{\arabic{paragraph} Other Paragraph}
Text here
```

But this is doing it by force and is not recommended. It misses the purpose of LaTeX.

In your case, try:

```
\arabic{section} .\arabic{paragraph}
```

Make sure, that all counters have to correct value.

Comment: Since the section counters are increased before the title is typeset, this will eventually print **1.1.1.2  2 New Paragraph** and not what you thought, most likely, followed by `1.1.1.4 4 Other Paragraph` -- the counter values are wrong here!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Only if you use secnumdepth=4. I tried it with no change to secnumdepth (3) and it gave the correct result.

Comment: Yes, but only because `secnumdepth=3` excludes the automatic stepping of the paragraph counter, as can be seen in the definition of `\@sect`