# Automatic Paragraph Numbering

Tags: numbering, titlesec

I am trying to create a LaTeX document that will automatically number paragraphs without the need to use `\paragraph` - the reason for this is that I am processing text that will be written by others who do not use LaTeX.

**Edit:** this is why the solution at [paragraph numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305220/paragraph-numbering) does not address my particular problem as it requires that `\paragraph` is replaced by `\item`.  This gives me the same problem as far as I can tell.

I have searched for several solutions which have helped me make progress and also warned that the use of `\everypar` can be problematic...  The current situation is that I **almost** have a solution but a new `\section` or `\subsection` causes the subsequent paragraph to drop the numbering as shown in the attached image.  Further paragraphs are numbered correctly.

Alternative numbering solutions would be acceptable to me - I have no real preference for whether the paragraph numbers flow consecutively through all sections or follow a within-section pattern.

My minimal working example is as follows (note I have a need to use the `\titlesec` package to make the document look pretty).  I am really scratching my head about this one - any help or pointers will be gratefully received!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\newcounter{para}
\newcommand*{\numberedparagraph}{%
\refstepcounter{para}
\textbf{\thepara.\space}
}

\let\oldep\everypar\newtoks\everypar  
\oldep{\the\everypar\everypar{\numberedparagraph}}

\begin{document}

\everypar{\numberedparagraph}

\section{Section 1}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section 2}

\lipsum[4-5]

\subsection{A Subsection}

\lipsum[6-7]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: See question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305220/paragraph-numbering?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for having a look at this.  I had already looked at that question and I think my situation is different.  The solution linked to just seems to replace the need to use ``\paragraph``  with a need to use ``\item`` so it gives me the same problem really...?

Comment: Perhaps [Non-Hierarchical Paragraph Numbering](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/numpara.shtml) may help. It uses `\everypar` but addresses `\section` etc.

Comment: I don't think it's a dup since OP wants an automated method (that is, use `\everypar` without interruption by sectioning commands).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot that link looks promising - thank you.  It seems that I have to redefine ``\@afterheading``.  This sounds a bit scary but I will try to figure it out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you to @NicolaTalbot for pointing me in the right direction.

The solution was to redefine `\@afterheading`.  This then wasn't quite right as the indentation of paragraph numbers was a bit awry so I solved that by setting the paragraph indentation to 0.

Corrected code and image follow:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em} % indent subsequent paragraphs

\newcounter{para}
\newcommand*{\numberedparagraph}{%
    \refstepcounter{para}
    \textbf{\thepara.\space}
}

\let\oldep\everypar\newtoks\everypar  
\oldep{\the\everypar\everypar{\numberedparagraph}}


\makeatletter %
\renewcommand{\@afterheading}{%
  \@nobreaktrue
\everypar{%
    \if@nobreak
      \@nobreakfalse
      \clubpenalty\@M
      \if@afterindent
      \else
    {\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
  \fi
\else
  \clubpenalty\@clubpenalty
  \everypar{\numberedparagraph}% <- modification
\fi
\numberedparagraph% <- modification
  }%
}


\begin{document}



\everypar{\numberedparagraph}

\section{Section 1}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section 2}

\lipsum[4-5]

\subsection{A Subsection}

\lipsum[6-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have extra spaced because of line endings without percent: → https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines

Comment: @Schweinebacke thanks for the tip.  This isn't something I currently understand but I will read the link, cheers.