# How to structure a TeX document by points

Tags: sectioning

I wonder if there is any already defined documentclass or command in order to label paragraphs by points. As Wittgenstein's *Tractacus*; [here](http://pmb.univ-fcomte.fr/2013/Kowalski.pdf) is an example.

More than in the example, I am also interested in reseting the points counter as well as indexing them by the current section.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126750/how-can-i-number-paragraphs-without-higher-level-counters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of no standard style but it is easy to set-up

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{pnum}[section]
\renewcommand{\thepnum}{\thesection.\arabic{pnum}}
\newcommand{\nump}{\noindent\refstepcounter{pnum}{\textbf{\thepnum}}.\enspace}

\begin{document}
\section{Families of cusp forms}

\nump
For a reductive group\dots

\nump
Any cusp form\dots

\section{Families of \( L \)-fuctions}

\nump
The most important\dots

\end{document}
```

The code introduces a new counter `pnum`, that is reset each section.  Its printed form `\thepnum` is specified to include the section number.  A new command `\nump` is then defined to start new paragraphs.  You can add vertical spacing by preceding the `\noindent` in that definition by e.g. `\smallbreak`.