# Less space between paragraphs?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126764/24406) shows how we may achieve a numbering of paragraphs with \S.

How may we in the following have the same spacing between §1 and §2 as the line spacing in the text above §1, without changing the line spacing in the latter? Also, how may the space between §1 and the text above conform to the same spacing?

The SECOND of the following codes is the solution I use based upon the answer accepted.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\S\arabic{paragraph}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}


Here are just some words to show the normal spacing between lines in the main document.
\paragraph{} 1st paragraph

\paragraph{} 2nd paragraph

\end{document}
```

````
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr,titlesec}
\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\S\arabic{paragraph}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titlespacing{\paragraph}
{15pt}{0pt}{-8pt}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}


Here are just some words to show the normal spacing between lines in the main document.
\paragraph{} 1st paragraph

\paragraph{} 2nd paragraph

\end{document}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your post, understood that you need to modify the vertical spacing before the tag `\paragraph`, is my understanding correct, then please use the below `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr,titlesec}
\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\S\arabic{paragraph}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

    \makeatletter
\titlespacing{\paragraph}
{0pc}{3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{10pt}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


Here are just some words to show the normal spacing between lines in the main document.
\paragraph{} 1st paragraph

\paragraph{} 2nd paragraph

\end{document}
```

Note: As you mentioned in comment that you are using `article` class file, hence I kept the same above vertical space for first level heading for `\paragraph` also...

Here is the solution I use on the basis of the accepted anser:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr,titlesec}
\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\S\arabic{paragraph}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titlespacing{\paragraph}
{15pt}{0pt}{-8pt}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}


Here are just some words to show the normal spacing between lines in the main document.
\paragraph{} 1st paragraph

\paragraph{} 2nd paragraph

\end{document}
```

Comment: My request is to have the same spacing between §1 and §2 as the line spacing in the text above, without changing the line spacing in the main texts.  Also, the space between the space above §1 and the line spacing in the main text is to be the same. My preferred document class is article. I update.

Comment: @Sapiens Updated, please refer....

Comment: I now managed to use your answer to obtain a solution, so I make the small adjustments to show it and accept your answer.

Comment: @Sapiens Glad to hear...

Comment: I indicate the solution I now use based upon your answer.